# ng-focus custom directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following code which displays a textbox along with the possible character limit:

```
<input id="noteAbstract" ng-model="abstract" max-length="{{abstractCharacterLimit}}" ng-trim="false" ng-focus="displayCounter=true" />

<span ng-show="displayCounter" id="noteAbstractCounter">{{abstractCharacterLimit - abstract.length}}</span>
```

I need to display the counter only when the focus is on the textbox. So I have set a scope variable 'displayCounter' to true on focus. However, the code is not working and the 'span' of counter is always hidden. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I tried invoking another method on ng-focus and that is working fine. So ng-focus is supported in my angular version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can check the angular version you are using? I tried with 1.1.1 it didnt work but with 1.2.1 version it works. Hence it would be better to user versions which later than 1.2.1

Here's the working jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/ztUsc/2/. As the version is 1.2.1 `ng-focus` is working.

Comment: Thanks. Problem was that I had a custom popover directive on the textbox.